# find 'all' using INNER JOIN rather LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm coding an app to sell cars, so i have a model called Anuncio(part that show the car, its in portuguese i dont know translate it) that has one Carmodel and Carmodel has one CarMake.

On anuncio controller i want load all Makes to populate combobox, so i'm using that:

```
$makes = $this->Anuncio->Carmodel->CarMake->find('list');
```

its working properly, but that find is bringing all makes, i want bring just makes that have at least one Carmodel recorded (something like INNER JOIN rather LEFT JOIN).

thanks

Comment: Why don't you ovveride find method and create your own query and results in your Model?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you didn't provide any code so I won't give you exact answer but I will write how it can be done.

You should override the model's list method and specially **list action**

```
class Carmodel extends AppModel {
var $belongsTo = array('User');

function find($type, $queryData = array()) {
switch ($type) {
  case 'list':
    //do the query that joins tables in way you want
  default:
    return parent::find($type, $queryData);
 }
```

}
 }

More can be found on http://debuggable.com/posts/implementing-different-types-for-cakes-modelfind-method:485030de-4778-456e-8400-44d84834cda3

I hope that it helps you. You can create your own $type in this method you don't need to override **list** action but you can create your own or just create new method in **Carmodel**

Comment: brother i understand what you said but thats not my issue, i just need retrieve all makes that has at least one carmodel. Example:
makes (Chev, Ford, lambo)
models (corvette, diablo)
so was bring just chev and lambo because theres no ford model.. am i clear?